# How can I save all retrieved records from database at the same time?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a wage calculation form that start from retrieving sum of wage from database and then, after user add some extra payment in order to calculate Net wage, save them back to database once again.

My problem was my code is only work to save one record at a time. What I need was to be able to save all records at the same time. So could you please help me.

```
<%
if Rs.eof then 
    response.write "<tr><td colspan=""9"">&nbsp;"
    call displayNotFoundRecord
    response.write "</td></tr>"
Else

    Do while Rs.AbsolutePage = strPageCurrent And Not Rs.EOF
    dim color 

            y = n mod 2
                if y > 0 then
                    color =  "EFF4FA"
                else 
                    color = "ffffff"
                end if                  

    if rs.fields.item("if_social_sec") = "True"  then
        displaytxt = "" 
        soc_sec_v = soc_sec
    else
        displaytxt = "none"
        soc_sec_v = 0
    end if 

    wage_v = rs.fields.item("Total")
    salary_v = rs.fields.item("lb_salary")

    if rs.fields.item("lb_type") = "perunit"  then
        salary_wage = wage_v
        displaytxt_w = "readonly class=""bgdisable""" 
        displaytxt_lb = "readonly class=""bgdisable"""      
    else
        salary_wage = salary_v
        displaytxt_w = ""
        displaytxt_lb = ""      
    end if

if_pm = request.form("if_pm")

pm_pay = rs.fields.item("lb_pmPay") 
    if if_pm <> "" then
        if_pm_v = pm_pay   
        disable_txt_pm = "readonly"     
    else
        if_pm_v = 0 
        disable_txt_pm = "readonly class=""bgdisable""" 
    end if  



%>
<form name="myform2_<%=n%>" action="salary_action.asp" method="POST">
<tr bgcolor="#<%=color%>"> 
<td class="btline difcursor" nowrap  width="7%">&nbsp;<%=rs.fields.item("lb_name")%></td>
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="working_day" id="working_day" value="<%=rs.fields.item("MaxOfdays")%>" size="7" <%=displaytxt_w%> onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);"></td>
<td class="btline "  nowrap width="10%"><input type="text" name="wage" id="wage" value="<%=salary_wage%>"  onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);"></td>
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="OT" id="OT" size="7" value="<%=if_OT_v%>" onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);" <%=disabled_ot%>></td>
<td class="btline center" nowrap  width="6%" ><input type="text"  name="OT_rate" id="OT_rate" size="5" value="<%=rs.fields.item("lbOT")%>" <%'=disabled_txt%> readonly class="bgdisable"></td>
<td class="btline center" nowrap  width="6%" ><input type="text" name="OT_amt" id="OT_amt" size="5" value="" <%'=disabled_txt%>  readonly class="bgdisable"></td>
<td class="btline center" nowrap  width="8%"  ><input type="text" name="soc_sec" id="soc_sec" size="7" value="<%=soc_sec_v%>" <%=disable_txt_soc%> onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);"></td>
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="pmPay" id="pmPay" size="7" value="<%=if_pm_v%>" onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);" <%'=disable_txt_pm%> readonly class="bgdisable"></td>
<td class="btline" nowrap style="padding-left: 10px" width="8%" ><input type="text" name="ex_pay" id="ex_pay" size="7" onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);"></td>
<td class="btline bold " width="10%"><input type="text" name="net_wage" id="net_wage" size="7"  readonly class="bgdisable">
<input type="hidden" name="lb_type" id="lb_type" size="7" value="<%=rs.fields.item("lb_type")%>">
<input type="hidden" name="date_from" id="date_from" size="7" value="<%=date_from_txt%>">
<input type="hidden" name="date_to" id="date_to" size="7" value="<%=date_to_txt%>">
<input type="hidden" name="lb_id" id="lb_id" size="7" value="<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>">
<input type="hidden" value="N" name="edit_salary">
</td>
<td class="btline"><input type="text" name="sar_note"  value="" size="14"></td>
<td class="btline"   > <input type="submit" value="Save1"></td>
</tr>


</form>
<%
        Rs.movenext
        n = n + 1       
    Loop
End if
Rs.close

set Rs=nothing
Call DBConnClose()
%>

<tr>
    <td colspan="12" align="center" style="padding:10px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save2">
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I need is to make "Save2" work. But right now only "Save1" that work.

Add (my script) :

```
<script>
var intervals = {};
function startCalc(sender){ 
  var key = sender.form.name;
  intervals[key] = setInterval(function() {
    calc(key);
  },1);
}
function calc(key){
  var oForm = document.forms[key];

working_day = oForm.working_day.value;

  wage = oForm.wage.value;
  lb_type_v = oForm.lb_type.value;

    if (lb_type_v == "daily")
    {
        wage = wage * working_day;
    }
    else
    {
        wage = wage;
    }

  OT_rate = oForm.OT_rate.value;
  OT = oForm.OT.value; 
      OT_amt = OT_rate * OT;
  soc_sec = oForm.soc_sec.value; 
  ex_pay= oForm.ex_pay.value; 
  pmPay = oForm.pmPay.value; 

 net_wage = (wage * 1) + (OT_amt * 1) - (soc_sec * 1) + (ex_pay * 1) + (pmPay * 1);

  oForm.OT_amt.value = OT_amt;
  oForm.net_wage.value = net_wage.toFixed(2);
}

function stopCalc(sender){
  var key = sender.form.name;
  clearInterval(intervals[key]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you will have to change each input name so that it is unique. You should also change the IDs to make them unique, depending on what you are doing with the IDs, but it's the name that is important if retrieving all of the records values in one go.

Easiest way to do this is to add your database ID to the name and ids.

So, for example, change this line...

```
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="OT" id="OT" size="7" value="<%=if_OT_v%>" onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);" <%=disabled_ot%>></td>
```

...to...

```
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="OT_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="OT_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=if_OT_v%>" onFocus="startCalc(this);" onBlur="stopCalc(this);" <%=disabled_ot%>></td>
```

(What this does is make each name and id unique by adding an underscore character and the lb_id value from your database.)

Then in the script where you retrieve your values (you didn't post this code so I am not sure what it looks like), you will need to open the same recordset and loop through checking for values.

So before you probably had lines like...

x = Request("OT")

You would instead do something like this...

```
'Open your recordset
Do while Rs.AbsolutePage = strPageCurrent And Not Rs.EOF
    x = Request("OT_" & Rs("lb_id"))
    '....all your other requests here
    'save to database here etc etc
Loop
```

Ok, here is your code modified (have a look at the comments to see where I have moved and removed things)...

```
<!--move form tag outside of table-->
<form name="myform2" action="salary_action.asp" method="POST"> 
<% 
if Rs.eof then  
    response.write "<tr><td colspan=""9"">&nbsp;" 
    call displayNotFoundRecord 
    response.write "</td></tr>" 
Else 

    Do while Rs.AbsolutePage = strPageCurrent And Not Rs.EOF 
    dim color  

            y = n mod 2 
                if y > 0 then 
                    color =  "EFF4FA" 
                else  
                    color = "ffffff" 
                end if                   

    if rs.fields.item("if_social_sec") = "True"  then 
        displaytxt = ""  
        soc_sec_v = soc_sec 
    else 
        displaytxt = "none" 
        soc_sec_v = 0 
    end if  

    wage_v = rs.fields.item("Total") 
    salary_v = rs.fields.item("lb_salary") 

    if rs.fields.item("lb_type") = "perunit"  then 
        salary_wage = wage_v 
        displaytxt_w = "readonly class=""bgdisable"""  
        displaytxt_lb = "readonly class=""bgdisable"""       
    else 
        salary_wage = salary_v 
        displaytxt_w = "" 
        displaytxt_lb = ""       
    end if 

if_pm = request.form("if_pm") 

pm_pay = rs.fields.item("lb_pmPay")  
    if if_pm <> "" then 
        if_pm_v = pm_pay    
        disable_txt_pm = "readonly"      
    else 
        if_pm_v = 0  
        disable_txt_pm = "readonly class=""bgdisable"""  
    end if   



%> 
<!--form tag moved outside of table-->
<tr bgcolor="#<%=color%>">  
<td class="btline difcursor" nowrap  width="7%">&nbsp;<%=rs.fields.item("lb_name")%></td> 
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="working_day_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="working_day_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" value="<%=rs.fields.item("MaxOfdays")%>" size="7" <%=displaytxt_w%> onFocus="startCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" onBlur="stopCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);"></td> 
<td class="btline "  nowrap width="10%"><input type="text" name="wage_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="wage_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" value="<%=salary_wage%>"  onFocus="startCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" onBlur="stopCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);"></td> 
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="OT_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="OT_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=if_OT_v%>" onFocus="startCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" onBlur="stopCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" <%=disabled_ot%>></td> 
<td class="btline center" nowrap  width="6%" ><input type="text"  name="OT_rate_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="OT_rate_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="5" value="<%=rs.fields.item("lbOT")%>" <%'=disabled_txt%> readonly class="bgdisable"></td> 
<td class="btline center" nowrap  width="6%" ><input type="text" name="OT_amt_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="OT_amt_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="5" value="" <%'=disabled_txt%>  readonly class="bgdisable"></td> 
<td class="btline center" nowrap  width="8%"  ><input type="text" name="soc_sec_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="soc_sec_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=soc_sec_v%>" <%=disable_txt_soc%> onFocus="startCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" onBlur="stopCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);"></td> 
<td class="btline center"  nowrap  width="8%"><input type="text" name="pmPay_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="pmPay_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=if_pm_v%>" onFocus="startCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" onBlur="stopCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" <%'=disable_txt_pm%> readonly class="bgdisable"></td> 
<td class="btline" nowrap style="padding-left: 10px" width="8%" ><input type="text" name="ex_pay_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="ex_pay_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" onFocus="startCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);" onBlur="stopCalc(<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>);"></td> 
<td class="btline bold " width="10%"><input type="text" name="net_wage_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="net_wage_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7"  readonly class="bgdisable"> 
<input type="hidden" name="lb_type_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="lb_type_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=rs.fields.item("lb_type")%>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="date_from_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="date_from_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=date_from_txt%>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="date_to_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="date_to_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=date_to_txt%>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="lb_id_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" id="lb_id_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>" size="7" value="<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>"> 
<input type="hidden" value="N" name="edit_salary_<%=rs.fields.item("lb_id")%>"> 
</td> 
<td class="btline"><input type="text" name="sar_note"  value="" size="14"></td> 
<td class="btline"   > <!--submit button removed--></td> 
</tr> 


<!--form tag removed-->
<% 
        Rs.movenext 
        n = n + 1        
    Loop 
End if 
Rs.close 

set Rs=nothing 
Call DBConnClose() 
%> 

<tr> 
    <td colspan="12" align="center" style="padding:10px;"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Save2"> 
    </td> 
</tr> 

<!--move form tag after end of table-->
</form>
```

...and your JavaScript (I just did it in Notepad so hopefully it works)...

```
<script> 
var intervals = {}; 
function startCalc(key){  
  intervals[key] = setInterval(function() { 
    calc(key); 
  },1); 
} 
function calc(key){ 
 // var oForm = document.forms[key]; 

working_day = document.getElementById("working_day_" + key).value; //oForm.working_day.value; 

  wage = document.getElementById("wage_" + key).value; //oForm.wage.value; 
  lb_type_v = document.getElementById("lb_type_" + key).value; //oForm.lb_type.value; 

    if (lb_type_v == "daily") 
    { 
        wage = wage * working_day; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        wage = wage; 
    } 

  OT_rate = document.getElementById("OT_rate_" + key).value; //oForm.OT_rate.value; 
  OT = document.getElementById("OT_" + key).value; //oForm.OT.value;  
      OT_amt = OT_rate * OT; 
  soc_sec = document.getElementById("soc_sec_" + key).value; //oForm.soc_sec.value;  
  ex_pay= document.getElementById("ex_pay_" + key).value; //oForm.ex_pay.value;  
  pmPay = document.getElementById("pmPay_" + key).value; //oForm.pmPay.value;  

 net_wage = (wage * 1) + (OT_amt * 1) - (soc_sec * 1) + (ex_pay * 1) + (pmPay * 1); 

  document.getElementById("OT_amt_" + key).value = OT_amt; //oForm.OT_amt.value = OT_amt; 
  document.getElementById("net_wage_" + key).value = net_wage.toFixed(2); //oForm.net_wage.value = net_wage.toFixed(2); 
} 

function stopCalc(key){ 
  clearInterval(intervals[key]); 
} 
</script>
```

You will also need to modify the page that your form submits to. Hopefully you can do this using the instructions I gave above???

Comment: Could you please suggest me with my added script. Because I think my script won't work when doing like this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see from your JavaScript that you are going to have to make changes to that too. I would suggest that you pass the database ID to your JS functions and then get your INPUT values using getElementById.

Comment: could you please elaborate? I really have no idea about javascript. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried your script, but it didn't work. :( Is it something about <form_<%=n%> and function startcalC, stopCalC that cause this unfunction ? Could you please help me on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I modified the FORM tag and startcalc and stopcalc functions. Try again.

Comment: Don't know how to thank you enough. You're so kind.. Now I can save all those at the same time.